# How to send input multiple columns data to keras model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, input, keras-layer

Given a numpy database of size (128, 47088), I need to send a data sequence to the training model, for example:

[This image is a sample for illustrative purposes only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1gMh.png)

Send the data from columns 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 , this string contains 640 data.
The next input is columns 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 , this sequence contains 640 data.

I'm trying to run using GRU, LSTM and Flatten without success.

Is it possible to perform this reshape within the model?
Or I need to prepare this data beforehand and already provide the dataset for the formatted model.

This is a sample of model training:

```
#np_input is a numpay array (128, 47088)
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.Input(shape=(128,)),
    keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer='l2'),
    keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer='l2'),
    keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer='l2'),
    keras.layers.Dense(np_output.shape[0], activation='sigmoid'),
    ])
model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001), loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['acc', 'mse'], run_eagerly=True)
model.summary()

# The training and testing base is split on axis 1, so the dataset is sent transposed to split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(np_input.T, np_output.T, test_size=0.2, shuffle=False, random_state=None)

hist = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, verbose=2, batch_size=2048, use_multiprocessing=True, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), callbacks=callbacks )
```

I'm trying to run using GRU, LSTM and Flatten without success.